# Mixing tags and map function inside react conditional

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx

I'm currently attempting to render a  header and a list of items if a conditional is met. As an example I'm using a todo app. If any of the todos are still marked as completed:false, I want to display a div with a header and the list of those incomplete todos. I'm getting a syntax error and trying to figure out what's wrong (Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","). Any help appreciated.

```
  incompleteTodos() {
   return this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-list">
        {this.incompleteTodos().length > 0 && (
        <h3>Incomplete</h3>
        {this.incompleteTodos().map((todo) => 
          <div key={todo.id} className="todo">
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(todo.id)}>Done</button>
            <span>{todo.task}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      )}
    </div>
   )
  }
```

Comment: Ideally you want to calculate your incomplete to-dos when state.todos changes and store them in a separate state property. Then use this property in your render method rather then your incompleteTodos method which will evaluate your todos for `!todo.conpleted` twice for every render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional rendering needs to return a single element. This is a requirement for anything in React that returns JSX - functions, components, classes.

Simply wrapping it in a fragment should do:

```js
{this.incompleteTodos().length > 0 && (
  <>
    <h3>Incomplete</h3>
    {this.incompleteTodos().map((todo) => 
      <div key={todo.id} className="todo">
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(todo.id)}>Done</button>
        <span>{todo.task}</span>
      </div>
    )}
  </>
)}
```

Remember, JSX is just a fancy syntax for calling `React.createElement()`. The reason this is a syntax error and not an error from React, is because `condition && (func() func2())` is invalid syntax. Meaning `this.incompleteTodos().length > 0 && (React.createElement() React.createElement())` is also invalid.

Here's a running (breaking) example that shows this is a JavaScript requirement, not just React.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a');
}

function b() {
  console.log('b');
}

true && (a() b());
```

What you're doing by wrapping the elements in a fragment is essentially wrapping the two functions with another function.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a');
}

function b() {
  console.log('b');
}

function wrapper() {
  a(); 
  b();
}

true && wrapper();
```

When you translate this example back to React, its now a single function call and valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: jeez. Thank you. I wish the debug error was more helpful and told me that.

Comment: @ssdev It's a JS syntax error, not necessarily related to React/JSX syntax and the necessity to return single nodes.